# apt update時にgpgエラーが発生して失敗する

Tags: ubuntu, apt, gpg

`sudo apt update`を行った際、以下のエラーで正常にupdateを実行できません。

```
$ sudo apt update

...

Err:2 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CDFB5FA52007B954

...

Reading package lists... Done                            
W: GPG error: http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CDFB5FA52007B954
E: The repository 'http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`apt-purge`にて`http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt`の除外も試みてみましたが、こちらの操作も同様にgpgエラーで阻まれてしまいました。

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt
Updating packages lists
W: GPG error: http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CDFB5FA52007B954
E: The repository 'http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease' is not signed.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

解決方法があればご教授をお願いします。

### 追記

> 試す環境が無いのでキーワードで検索しただけですが、以下のページが参考になるかもしれません。

`$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys` こちらを実行してみましたが、以下の結果となりエラーが発生しました。

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 

Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.50autdvTgt/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys CDFB5FA52007B954
gpg: key CDFB5FA52007B954: public key "Metasploit <metasploit@rapid7.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.50autdvTgt/home:manuelschneid3r.asc.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 7
gpg:       skipped new keys: 7
```

`sudo apt update`の実行結果についても同様のエラー内容で失敗しています。

### 実行環境

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Livepatch** > **その他のソフトウェア**
から

`http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt`

の項目を削除することでエラーを解消することができました。

Answer (score 0):

試す環境が無いのでキーワードで検索しただけですが、以下のページが参考になるかもしれません。

[GPG error when updating, key expired #7336](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/7336)

> ```
> $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys CDFB5FA52007B954
> ```

Comment: 実行してみましたが、エラーを解決することができませんでした。エラー内容を追記しました。